# var = string[indexpath.row], Prepareforsegue, calling string to be nav bar title (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "packtofeedsegue"){
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        var lastviewed = userids[indexPath!.row]
        println(lastviewed)
    }
}
```

Second view controller:

```
var lastviewed = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = lastviewed
}
```

I'm trying to `preparesegue` to set a variable to the row text and then call that text in the next view controller to be the title of the nav bar.

Im getting: `Cannot assign value of type [(String)] to a value of String? for self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = lastviewed`.

When I changed `var lastviewed = [String]()` to `var lastviewed = String()`, there is no error but nothing shows up: println showed the right text so the right information is going into `prepareforsegue`

Comment: is lastViewed a list of Strings or a single string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[String]` means "an array of objects of type `String`". What you want is `String`.

```
var lastViewed = ""
```

Put the title configuration into `viewWillAppear`. It should be enough to do

```
self.title = lastViewed
```

Assign to view controller in `prepareForSegue`:

```
let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondController
destination.lastViewed = userIds[indexPath!.row]!
```

Comment: Tried that. Mentioned this at the bottom of my post. Sorry I'm noob.

Comment: do i need to set a certain class for the second viewcontroller or connect the viewcontrollers in a certain way????, because when i println(lastviewed) on the second viewcontroller nothing comes up

Comment: Yep. The second view controller should have the custom class that contains the variable (you set it in Interface Builder). You have to cast the view controller from segue.destinationViewController.

Comment: thanks man got it to work, u da best dont let anyone ever tell u otherwise.